# How can I get the property path in template (ractive.js)

Tags: ractivejs

I'm writing a page with ractive.js and Kendo UI. The page is generated by a definition, the definition will translate to a (ractive.js) template, and render to a page finally. In the page, I also use the Kendo UI's MVVM library for binding the data. but there is a problem that the Kendo UI MVVM needs the full path to bind. So, is there any function in ractive.js can get the full path of the property?

```
    {{#.MaskTextBox}}
    <span>
        <input data-role="maskedtextbox"
               placeholder="{{PlaceHolder}}"
               data-mask="{{Mask}}"
               data-bind="value: {{getPath(Value)}}" />
    </span>
    {{/.MaskTextBox}}
```

I hope the `getPath` function can return the property path like `"MaskTextBox.Value"`.

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is more of a question: what's your reason for using Ractive and Kendo UI together? They have overlapping responsibilities; using both is like using jQuery and MooTools on the same project!

Comment: @RichHarris I like to use the Ractive, it's much better than Kendo UI on template, and I was asked to use Kendo UI's controls.

Comment: I think the best you can hope for is to keep track of where you are in the template and reconstruct the keypath - here's a contrived example of what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/aL4U7/

Comment: @RichHarris It seems there is no other easy solutions. Thank you  for your reply and your Ractive. :)